# How do I force the menu to NOT pause my game?

Tags: borderlands-2

While I play single player and go into any menu (<kbd>esc</kbd>, inventory, etc) it pauses my game. How can I go into menu without pausing the game?

Comment: Is there a practical reason why you'd want that?

Comment: I want the slot machine to keep going while sorting through my inventory and thus not wasting time. Also sometimes i just want to wait for enemies to move while looking at my inventory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way the you can sort through your inventory without everything freezing up is by playing multiplayer.

If you play it as single-player, you'll have to keep pausing the game every time you open the menu.

So my advice? Open up your lobby; set your connection type to "Public". That'll allow others in Matchmaking to find and join you, then allowing you to take advantage of that to not have menus pause the games.

Comment: LAN yourself, Borderlands2, x2. Use Roland for ammo regen, an increased difficulty, and as a doorman.

Comment: @Mazura Roland only appears in certain missions

Comment: I meant Salvador. In Bordelands1, I keep an extra Roland standing around for ammo.